# ext2explore for windows doesn't read ext3/4 sparse files what does?

Tags: windows, mount, ext3, ext4, sparseimage

I have some sparse files that I want to read/copy to windows but I can't find a FS reader that works any suggestions?

EDIT: to clarify the sparse files are living on an ext3 partition it's this partition that I can't read correctly.

I had a 70 odd gig file that was sparsed and only a few kb made it over to windows (the file was mostly full)

I was trying to stay away from kernel space mountable drivers but if anybody has testimony of Ext2 IFS and the like working without problems I might take the risk.

copying sparse correctly is a must (it doesn't have to stay spare at dest)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

colinux is one answer.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/colinux/files/coLinux-stable/
then
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/131903/colinux-centos53.exe

http://blog.gbraad.nl/2009/04/centos-53-image-for-colinux.html for setup rpm and network setup.

I don't trust half the windows kernel drives and this seems stable.

Note if you installed to C:\coLinux\ instead of C:\Program Files\coLinux\ you need to change all of the centos text files to the same (manual recommend i use C:\coLinux)

colinux seems to expect you to build your own colinux+favdistro as that link I gave is like 2009 or something.. 
Someone revive andlinux or Portable Ubuntu!

I have talked to the ext2explore dev and he says he will make an update that reads sparse.

If anyone knows a  readonly alternative like this in the mean time please post!

Doe this and restart to get networking working.

cat > /etc/sysconfig/network << END
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=localhost.localdomain
END

You'll then have to setup samba/CIFS to share the mount  you made.

I had to set cobd3="\Device\Harddisk1\Partition3"  in run.txt to detect the partion on /dev/cobd3

Comment: This is the only answer I can find to read sparse with out installing a system driver for windows which I don't trust. No read only drive I found read sparse :(